# Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe for a cross-domain site.  I want to read the DOM of the iframe, which I believed was possible because using the inspector, I can even modify the DOM of an iframe.  Every way I attempt to read it, however, I run into the same origin policy.  All I want, is the content loaded in my local DOM, from the iframe.  I thought it would be as simple as `$(document.body).find('iframe').html()`, but that's returning the empty string.

I really hope there's a way to do this since the work I've been doing for the last several days has been predicated on this being do-able.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do this - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17262334/888177

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can't. [XSS protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Cross site contents can not be read by javascript. No major browser will allow you that. I'm sorry, but this is a design flaw, you should drop the idea.

**EDIT**

Note that if you have editing access to the website loaded into the iframe, you can use [postMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393545/421009) (also see the [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging))

Comment: if you meant design (flow) flaw, then no, it is not a flaw, this was implemented for security.

Comment: In that case i misunderstood then

Comment: In the end, I didnt need to use an iframe for what I was doing.

Comment: good to hear that you could resolve it

Comment: For reference, cross-domain same-origin-policy means that hostname, port and protocol must all be the same - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy (eg app1.example.com and app2.example.com are different; example.com and www.example.com are different)

Comment: Note: You can use window.postMessage to communicate between iframe and the main window.

Comment: CORS is not an option here. It does not enable JS to read the DOM of a cross-origin frame.

Answer (score 26):

There is a simple way.

1. You create an iframe which has for source something like "http://your-domain.com/index.php?url=http://the-site-you-want-to-get.com/unicorn
2. Then, you just get this url with `$_GET` and display the contents with `file_get_contents($_GET['url']);`

You will obtain an iframe which has a domain same than yours, then you will be able to use the `$("iframe").contents().find("body")` to manipulate the content.

Comment: Could you please explain the detail. Thank you very much@@

Comment: Sorry to be late, I didn't noticed.

1. Create a php page that display the content of the page you want from a GET parameter.

content.php
`<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>`

2. Then, in your main page, add an iframe that will load this page.
`<iframe src="content.php?url=http://google.com">`

3. It will display the wanted page in the iframe. Content.php is from your domain, so you can manipulate the iframe content with JS, without violating cross-origin policy.
`var $iframeBody = $("iframe").contents().find("body"); $iframeBody.css("background", blue");`

Comment: If for whatever reason you don't want an iframe you could make an ajax call to your php too

Comment: @Bharata: Wrong. If you load the file contents into an iframe, you can access its inner DOM just like normal same-origin iframe.

Comment: Note that if you use this method, be very careful since this will allow your server to be used as a de facto proxy. Therefore this should be behind authentication and/or the list of permitted websites should be restricted.

Answer (score 9):

If you have access to the iframed page you could use something like [easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM#readme) to make function calls in the iframe and return the data.

If you don't have access to the iframed page you will have to use a server side solution.
With PHP you could do something quick and dirty like:

```
    <?php echo file_get_contents('http://url_of_the_iframe/content.php'); ?>
```

Comment: i dont have access to the iframed page and a server-side solution is pretty much out of the question, because i am using cocoahttpserver (the server is running on an iphone)

Comment: In that case it's not possible. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy for more detailed info.

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman

Comment: thanks allot for the idea, this answer and this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29501376/1521606, helped me create a workaround! cheers

Comment: @devmatt, with `file_get_contents($_GET['url'])` you can get page content, but you can not get DOM content! Wrong answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an access to that domain/iframe that is loaded, then you can use window.postMessage to communicate between iframe and the main window.

Read the DOM with JavaScript in iframe and send it via postMessage to the top window.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: How can we read the DOM in iframe with js? It's possible, isn't it?

Comment: You read the DOM as you would normally. For example document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]; After that use the window.postMessage to send the DOM object you just read in the iframed window to the window that is hosting the iframe window.

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround to achieve it.

1. First, bind your iframe to a target page with relative url. The browsers will treat the site in iframe the same domain with your website.
2. In your web server, using a rewrite module to redirect request from the relative url to absolute url. If you use IIS, I recommend you check on [IIRF module](http://iirf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Do you mean server sends http redirect to foreign location? If so, it doesn't work in at least Firefox 9. I assume other browsers won't be fooled by that either

Comment: He means rewriting the request on the server, so the client has no idea that it isn't the right url