# Get Cross-Domain iFrame content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I would like to know how I can get content from an IFrame cross-domain?

I have no problem getting content from a non-cross-domain iFrame, but when it's located on another domain, JavaScript doesn't allow access.

Comment: Use a proxy script on your server which gets the content and passes it on to your page... You can then communicate with that script via Ajax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short of requesting it via a proxy on your own server, you can't.

The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents it (and for good reason; I would be very unhappy if you loaded my banking site in your iframe and read all my account details)

Answer (score 11):

You use [Cross Document Messaging](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#web-messaging), [here's an example](http://www.dotrob.com/demo/messaging/parent-2.html).  Here's the significant code from the parent page:

```
window.addEventListener('message', receiver, false);
function receiver(e) {
    document.getElementById('message').value = e.data;
}
function update_child() {
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    el.contentWindow.postMessage('Updated from parent', '*');
}
```

The child page has identical code - note that you need to be able to implement the interface on both domains for this to work, either by yourself, if you control both, or in co-operation with the owner of the other domain.  In production code you should [set (and check) the origin](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#dom-messageevent-origin).

Comment: I can't control the two domains.

Comment: your example is not working. getting error in console because iframe element not found.

Comment: @MayankModi Sorry for the late response, I have added the `iframe` back in, not sure what happened there