# How can I assign an href to be embedded within a tag?

Tags: asp.net, html, browser, href, jquery-ui-accordion

An href's target attribute can be set to display on a separate page by assigning "_blank" to it; e.g., in my site *www.DuckbilledPlatypiRUs.org*, I could link to another site this way:

```
<a href="http://www.BigSurGarrapata.com" target="_blank">Garrapata</a>
```

If I leave the target attribution out, the href'd site replaces the existing site on the browser's current page.

But I want to have the page/site display, not in the user's browser per se, but embedded within my site, in one of its tags; in my case, inside the Contents of an accordion "fold." I tried to get that to work this way:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Garrapata</h3>
    <div id="garrapataFold"><a href="http://www.BigSurGarrapata.com" target="#garrapataFold">Big Sur Garrapata site</a></div>
```

IOW, it's targeting itself; but that doesn't work; it acts as if I had assigned "_blank" to href's target attribute.

So am I going about this completely wrong, or am I close but don't know which value to assign to the target attribute?

Comment: Typically when I want to embed a page from another site within my own project I've used an iframe tag - there is also probably an ajax option but I'm not not savvy enough with ajax to explain how

Comment: I thought iFrame was deprecated...?

Comment: nope - still part of the html5 spec, but the ajax option is probably better, but more complicated.  in any case it's a quick way to see if the embedded page will work in the accordion

Comment: Adding the following just plops an empty rectangle into the content area:                 <div><iframe>http://www.BigSurGarrapata.com"</iframe></div>

Comment: It's difficult, although not impossible, to get content from other domains to appear in an iFrame. I believe the same is also true of loading content using Ajax, due to the Same Origin Policy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474484/get-cross-domain-iframe-content

Comment: @Clay - <iframe src="BigSurGarrapata.com"></iframe> - book mark this link http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: @fnostro: Isn't that the site Paul Irish has declared war on?

Comment: @Clay - kinda missing the point there buddy :) W3Schools is a HUGE compendium of basic knowledge, but it's not the only one I use, point is you should have a whole arsenal of bookmarks of your favorite reference materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works well:

```
<div><iframe src="http://www.bigsurgarrapata.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe></div>
```

...for the most part; not everybody allows themselves to be "confined" this way; flicker shows an errror message, that they don't allow such, and netflix just takes over the browsing session.