# Determine what was parsed in JSON for IE8 and less

Tags: jquery, json

All,
I've got the following code:

```
onDone: function (e, data) {
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data.result);
var uploadType = result.upload_type;
var filename = result.name;
var insert_id = result.insert_id;
}
```

When I run this I get the following error from IE:

```
Message: 'upload_type' is null or not an object
```

When I do a console.log(data.result) in Chrome I get the following data:

```
 [{
    "name": "1_3266_671641333369_14800358_42187036_5237378_n.jpg",
    "size": 35535,
    "type": "image\/jpeg",
    "url": "\/web\/upload\/1_3266_671641333369_14800358_42187036_5237378_n.jpg",
    "thumbnail_url": "\/web\/upload\/thumbnails\/1_3266_671641333369_14800358_42187036_5237378_n.jpg",
    "delete_url": "\/web\/upload.php?file=1_3266_671641333369_14800358_42187036_5237378_n.jpg",
    "delete_type": "DELETE",
    "upload_type": "video_montage",
    "insert_id": "288"
}]
```

I'm trying to see why I'm getting the error message in IE8 but I can't see what is being parsed. When I did do an alert like this:

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data.result);
alert(result)
```

I was getting null but no idea why.

Any help is greatly appreciated on how to read it or why my results of the parsed JSON are null even though there is data in my returned string!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this and it's an issue because IE doesn't support XHR uploads. You can find a detail explanation of this by checking out this post:

[jquery file upload - IE done callback data.result issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814068/jquery-file-upload-ie-done-callback-data-result-issue)

That didn't quite solve my needs however because that code only worked for IE and I needed to work across browsers. I updated my code a little bit and if you check out the accepted answer here:

[jquery file upload - IE callback results in object Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443930/jquery-file-upload-ie-callback-results-in-object-object)

You'll find out how to handle a JSON response from IE for an XHR type of upload!

Answer (score 1):

`data.result` is already an object.

And you're getting `null` because jQuery returns `null` when the parameter of [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.7.2/jQuery.parseJSON) isn't of type `string`

Comment: @user1048676: Remove the `parseJSON` line.  Also, try `data.result[0].upload_type`, your data is an array (of objects).

Comment: As @Rocket suggests. Remove the line with `parseJSON` so jQuery won't return `null`. After this you should be able to get the data with `data.result[0].upload_type`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this in IE:

```
alert(data.result);
```

That should give you the string value of the JSON.

Comment: that just gives me [object Object]

Comment: `parseJSON` is meant to parse a string.  If `alert(data.result)` gives you `[object Object]` that means it might already be parsed.  Try `alert(data.result[0].name)`.

Comment: @cdmckay: I didn't realize that (I'm out of caffiene).  `data.result` is *already* parsed.

Comment: @Rocket: I see.  That means all the OP needs to do is index the array.

Comment: @cdmckay I get undefined when I try alert(data.result[0].name)

Comment: @user1048676: I suggest using the IE8 developer tools (push F12) to breakpoint the object and then inspect its contents.

Comment: @cdmckay: I hate IE's dev tools, the suck =/

Comment: @Rocket: Agreed, but there's not much other choice here short of including `json2.js` and `stringify`ing the `data.result` object to see what's in there.

Comment: @cdmckay: There's [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite/).  It's a bookmarklet. :-P

Answer (score 0):

`data.result` is *already* parsed, no need for `$.parseJSON`.  Remove this line:

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data.result);
```

Also, your JSON object is an array (of objects).  Try getting the property from the 1st object in the array.

```
var uploadType = data.result[0].upload_type;
```

Comment: I get undefined when I do that.

Comment: What does `console.log(data.result[0])` say?

Comment: I think IE just prints the incredibly useful `[Object object]` when you log an object.

Comment: It just says [ and then it gives me an error and says the result is undefined.

Comment: @cdmckay: That's why I hate IE's dev tools.  I use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite/) :-P

Comment: @user1048676: It prints a `'['`?  That means it might *not* be parsed.  Do me a favor.  `console.log(typeof data.result)`.

Comment: @user1048676: Didn't you say that `alert(data.result);` alert said `[object Object]`?  How is that possible?

Comment: @Rocket In chrome it gives me the string, in IE8 it gives me [object Object]

Comment: @user1048676 Include `json2.js` from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/ and do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` and tell us what it says.

Comment: @cdmckay I did this in in Chrome and got the following message: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: @user1048676: Try that in IE.

Comment: @Rocket I get console is not defined in IE

Comment: @user1048676: Open the dev tools, then load your page.  IE is stupid, and `console` only exists if the dev tools are opened *first*.  Or try `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` instead.

Comment: @Rocket I changed it to console.log(JSON.stringify(data.result)) and got the following: LOG: {"length":1,"prevObject":{"length":1},"selector":".contents()"}

Comment: @user1048676: That's not the same object you show in your question.

Comment: @Rocket When I do console.log(data.result) in Chrome that is the object that I get back in my console.

Comment: @Rocket And if I run console.log(data.result) in IE I get the object Object

Comment: @user1048676: So `console.log`ing the same object gives different results in different browsers?  Just out of curiosity, where is this object coming from?  What is `onDone` a callback for?

Comment: @Rocket I'm using the following theme: http://revaxarts-themes.com/?t=whitelabel. The onDone is basically a callback when an image is uploaded using their Form -> Multi File Upload. I'm basically returning some data from an upload.php script that is handling the upload.

Comment: @user1048676: Why would `upload.php` return different values in IE and Chrome?

Comment: @Rocket I have no idea. I can add the script to my question so you can see it. There is nothing out of the ordinary that I'm doing so I'm not sure.

Comment: @Rocket The PHP upload file is actually this one: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/upload.class.php. The line that basically returns the file info is line 347.

Comment: @Rocket Could this happen because all of my files aren't in the same directory (but all in the same domain)? It looks like there is an issue already documented for this: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/659

Comment: @cdmckay Do you think it could happen because of my files aren't in the same directory (but all in the same domain)?

Comment: @user1048676: I don't know ='(

Comment: @Rocket Just in case you were curious, I narrowed the issue down even further. Check out this post on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814068/jquery-file-upload-ie-done-callback-data-result-issue I still don't know how to solve my issue but should shed some light for you on why different browsers are returning different results!

Comment: @Rocket Just an FYI, I finally solved it. Check out my answer on here to find out what I had to do.

Comment: @cdmckay Just an FYI, I finally solved it. Check out my answer on here to find out what I had to do.