# File upload not working in ie11

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code(which calls the cotroller in mvc3) which is working fine in chrome but it is not working in IE11:

```
$('#fileUpload').fileupload({
url: baseUrl + 'UploadAttachments',
    dataType: 'html',
    formData: { formId: $("#SelectedFormId").val(), formCompletedStatusId: $("#FormCompletedStatusId").length > 0 ? $("#FormCompletedStatusId").val() : $("#FormCompleteStatusId").val(), formRejectedStatusId: $("#FormRejectedStatusId").val() },
    add: function (e, data) {
        jqXHRData = data
        $("#fileUploadFileName").val(jqXHRData.files[0].name);
    },
done: function (event, data) {
        $("#tabs-2").html('');
        $("#tabs-2").html(data.result);
        jqXHRData = "";
    },
    fail: function (event, data) {
        if (data.files[0].error) {
        alert(data.files[0].error);
        }
    },
    submit: function (e, data) {
    }
});
);
```

The following event triggers the function:

```
$("#btnUpload").live("click", function () {
if (jqXHRData != "") {
    if (checkFileExtention(jqXHRData.files[0].name)) {
        AjaxLoading();
        setTimeout(function () { jqXHRData.submit(); }, 1000);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated!!! bdw what version of jquery you are using???

Comment: Hi Guruprasad, Thanks for reply , I am using 1.7.1 jquery version.

Comment: are you using any plugin?? what is that `fileupload` function!!!

Comment: fileupload is from jquery plugin jquery.forms.js

Comment: Which OS you are using Windows 8 or 7??

Comment: Windows 8 ..but i don't think it has anything to do with it.. Or does it?

Comment: It is the one which we need to check mainly.. I'll explain it as answer!!

Comment: I mis-read somewhere actually it won't and sorry for that info!! Just go through **[THIS LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535263(v=vs.85).aspx)**  and check out the answer **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814068/jquery-file-upload-ie-done-callback-data-result-issue)**. It might help you!!!

Comment: Thanks Guruprasad for your time !! I will check that..

Comment: Sure!! I'll try to research on this and will let you know if I get any info!!! For you information Microsoft will soon remove IE from browsers list as there are going to launch new browser called **Spartan**