# javascript iframe content javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe)

I want to get know how I can get data from other websites/other domain name in javascript. I see many posts that's say it's impossible but I don't think it's impossible there is should some way that I am not able to find out! Is it possible to get data from Iframe or direct and set it to div and other element? Let me know. Note: Content/data are coming from another page.  For example, my site is `abc.com` and gets data from `xyz.com`.

Comment: Imagine if any site on the Web could open an iframe to `mail.google.com` and scrape the mail of any vistors who are logged in to Gmail.  Tremendous security problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason people say it's impossible is because it's impossible.

It's impossible for a reason. Security.

Comment: as I told you it's possible [take a Look this!](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/)

Comment: @Capripio: This uses Yahoo's YQL library, which fetches pages through a Yahoo proxy server.  Yes, it works, but it is not a pure-javascript solution.  Also, you will fetch pages as Yahoo sees them, e.g., not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some server-side technology, like PHP, at the same domain as your JS downloading the content for you.

PHP proxy example: http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Or you can configure a reverse proxy using **mod_proxy** on your Apache's **httpd.conf**. It's useful when you are working with APIs on a different domain:

```
ProxyPass /app/api http://other_domain:8080/api
ProxyPassReverse /app/api http://other_domain:8080/api
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use e.g. `php` to get the link, and then proxy it from javascript.