# How te remove google ads from an iframe hosted on other domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, ads

I'm looking for some javascript or jquery script to remove google ads from an iframe document, which is hosted on a different domain.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can't. You can't even access the iframe in the first place, how much more the ad within it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see [Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe)

Unless you have control of some script in that frame, in which case you can do some fancy postMessage stuff, but if you have control, then remove the ads there :)

Comment: I can add script to the framed (nestes?) document. Any idea?

Comment: If you can add script to the iframe at the source, then remove the ads there ;)