# how to apply styles for the external websites during runtime

Tags: javascript

I am extracting the data from an external website ([for instance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_Reuters)).

My application shows:

1. The extracted  data.
2. The website link as the source of the extraction.

When I click on the website link it will redirect to the site.  Now I want to **highlight the extracted data in that website**.  How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that.

An option could be to open the link in an `iframe` and then highlight the text you want with [any available text highlight jQuery plugin](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/).

However, **it is not possible to access contents of an** `iframe` **from a different domain due to security reasons** (see [Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe)).

So, there seems to be no way to achieve what you need.  At least not without the aid of any browser plugin, but that does not look as an option to me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in php:

```
$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_Reuters";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
echo $contents;
```

Comment: use it in ajax. then highlight the content in page.

Comment: OP wants to go to the extracted website and highlight the data there. So on the external website. Your example only shows how to display the data on another website, not even how to highlight anything.

Comment: the highlight can be done with jquery & css. but it is for showing the data in own page. anyway, my mistake.