# screengrab from a youtube video in javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I have a user requirement in which I want to take a screengrab of what is playing on a youtube video at the moment. I have read about rendering to canvas, but it seems to take dom elements, and not the current flash video position. Is this possible? I can't use browser extensions, it has to be a button on the site that does this.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: How about if I use the HTML5 renderer?

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible with a Flash video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to do this. Getting a youtube video as a dom video element is possible using the HTML5 embed option. The problem is youtube videos reside in an iframe, and due to [cross-domain security restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe), you will not be able to access the video dom element, which is necessary to draw it to a canvas.

Comment: How about if it's on a customized youtube channel? is it still embedded in an iframe?

Comment: The `object` element is the only alternative embed youtube provides, however, that does not support HTML5. See https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters