# How do i get content from an iframe using jquery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, cross-browser, cross-domain

I inserted an iframe tag to my HTML page and i want to hide some contents in that iframe. This iframe content is from different origin. I used **$("#iFrame").contents()** but it is not working. Is this a issue related with browser?

Comment: How did you manage to ignore all suggestions when starting to write this question?

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't. Due to browser security restrictions and preventing XSS, most browsers will prevent this. In Google Chrome, you can override this by adding the [`--disable-web-security`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083677/1519377) parameter when running the browser.

Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe) (possible duplicate) SO post.