# How to embed a specific div from external website into Rshiny Iframe

Tags: iframe, shiny

I want to embed a table from external website, such as [investing.com](http://www.investing.com/quotes/streaming-forex-rates-%E2%80%93-majors) but I'm finding difficult embedding a specific `div`, in current example the exchange rate table has **id =** `cr1`. How can I only embed the table itself?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Getting A specific div from external website"), 
                mainPanel(fluidRow(                    
                  tags$iframe(seamless="seamless",src="http://www.investing.com/quotes/streaming-forex-rates-%E2%80%93-majors", height=600, width=1000)
                )
        )
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**I want table in Red only**

[image]

Comment: What language is this? You tagged your question with JavaScript, but your code isn't JavaScript.

Comment: Its R, I need to use `Javascript` to perform that call. I will remove the unnecessary tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cross-origin policy block you from hiding parts of the iframe (at-least it seems to do it for me) but you can download the table and display it,

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      HTML(
        '
      $(document).ready(function(){
        // Should work if not blocked
        $("#myiframe").attr("src","http://www.investing.com/quotes/streaming-forex-rates-%E2%80%93-majors");

        $("#myiframe").load( function(){
          console.log("UPDATED");
          var iframe   = $("#myiframe").contents(),
            tbl = iframe.find("#cr1").clone();
          iframe.find("html").replaceWidth(tbl);
        });
      });
        '
      )
    )
  ),
  titlePanel("Getting A specific div from external website"), 
    mainPanel(fluidRow(   
      tags$iframe(id="myiframe",seamless="seamless",src="", height=600, width=1000),
      dataTableOutput("tbl1")
    )
  )
))

library(httr)
library(XML)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  url <- "http://www.investing.com/quotes/streaming-forex-rates-%E2%80%93-majors"
  page.DOM <- content(GET(url))
  tables   <- readHTMLTable(page.DOM)
  exchng.tbl <- tables$cr1

  # cr1
  output$tbl1 <- renderDataTable({
    exchng.tbl
  })

})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That still takes in the whole page

Comment: There's at-least a table at the bottom of the page, when I run the Javascript I get an error. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe) link. I don't think it's possible to edit out parts in the iframe unless you proxy it.