# Is it possible to modify the page being loaded in the cross-domain <iframe>?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

There is an iframe that is loaded from an external domain.

Is it possible to access the DOM of that iframe and change something in it?

If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross domain iframe issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue)

Answer (score 0):

No i think,
Because i have tried this a long time ago and when i did some research, i found that there some js techniques which allow us to modify that but it will be on the same server who is giving you the page.

Like if i have google.com in my iframe then it depends on google.com, if it will allow me or not, i do not remember the technique sorry, thats why i simply write No for that.

But why you are using iframes?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do that using [postMessage](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage) if you have access to the code on both domains.