# Removing all anchor title attributes in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to remove all anchor title attributes in all links within an iframe so that when you hover over them you don't get the title?

I know I can do something like the following but for some reason it isn't working.

```
$("iframe").load(function() {
    $("iframe").contents().find("a").each(function(index) {
      $(this).attr('title','');
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the iframe loaded from the same domain, protocol etc.

Comment: No, completely different domain. I'm just trying to kill the anchor hovers because they are quite annoying in this instagram plugin @adeneo

Comment: See this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe

Comment: ^ That's the reason for asking, the same origin policy prohibits you from accessing content not loaded from the same domain, so basically you can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If iframe uses same protocol and domain, you can change iframe's content.

Different protocol or domain will generate an Security Exception.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you on the same domain:

```
 $('iframe').load(function(){
        $(this).contents().find('a').removeAttr('title');
 })
```

If you are not on the same domain, it will not work. See the following SO Question/Answer:

[Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe)

Comment: Doesn't work. `$(this).contents()` returns nothing. `$(this)` returns the iframe however

Comment: I see your issue is cross domain. This will only work same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Given the contents of iFrame is from same domain you can use the following for every anchor tag

```
$('a').removeAttr('title');
```

Comment: My problem is it's not getting the contents

Comment: Great, so how do I do it if it isn't the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

**Javascript:** [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/drpde1u3/)

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;

var links = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].removeAttribute("title");
}
```

**Jquery: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uc9uzswu/)**

```
setTimeout( function () {
      $("#iframeId").contents().find("a").removeAttr("title");
}, 1000 );
```