# Rename tableau view title in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, tableau-api

I have a Tableau view and I need to change the name(span element) of this view.I have not access to this view(it is an example, name is "CT School Districts by Income and Grade Level Equivalents, 2009-13"). Can I use the javascript or jquery to change the span element? I'm trying a lot approaches, nothing working.

```
<iframe src="https://public.tableau.com/views/CTSchoolDistrictsbyIncomeandGradeLevels2009-13/Sheet1?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&:toolbar=n&:showVizHome=no"
        width="645" height="955"></iframe>
```

jquery not work:

```
$("span:contains('CT School Districts by Income )")[0].replaceWith("Test");
```

Comment: You cannot get elements within iframes unless your code is on the same domain.

Comment: why? inside iframe i have generated html, I think, it's possible, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe

Comment: any ideas how to use postMessage to change span in iframe body?