# Manipulate ID element of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

[image: here the inspect]I have attach iframe to my site and I have try many time to put value to iframe text box. But not working, Is there any way to put value to iframe.

I have try with

```
var test = $('#text').contents();

 test.value="WELCOME";
```

Here My example.com/test/index.html

```
      <html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <label>Filed1
        <label>
           <textarea id="text"></textarea>
     </div>
      </body>
       </html>
```

My iframe:

```
   <iframe id ="test" width="350" height="400" 
   src="www.example.com/test/index.html" frameborder="1"  ></iframe>
```

Comment: Is the `iframe` and the page on the same domain?

Comment: no,cross domain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe)

Comment: can post the error on console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **IFrame** there is a property named `contentWindow`, as so the frame contains the whole html page inside ; and there is the **document** which you can access to the inner contents of the iframe.

```
// html:
// <iframe id="a"></iframe>

var f = document.getElementById("a");
var fd = f.contentWindow.document;
```

to clear the content or address the `src` :

```
// clear content 
element.src = "about:blank";
```

to write the content:

```
// write new content
var newHtml = '<html><body><textarea id="aa">Hello</textarea></body>'
f.contentWindow.document.open();
f.contentWindow.document.write(newHtml);
f.contentWindow.document.close();
```

and to access inner content elements:

```
fd.getElementById("aa").value = "orange";

// or in JQuery :    
$("#aa",fd).val("Hello again");
```

Comment: Yaa! Its Work, Show "Hello". But I want put value on text area.

Comment: Wah! Working, But the all other iframe's element erases,

Comment: did you write to it? don't . that was just a demo. address the iframe with src, and then access elements with iframe,contentWindow.document

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `val` ?, **it will work on only same domain link** !

```
$('#test').contents().find('#text').val('WELCOME');
```

Please make sure you put the javascript AFTER the `iframe` or put this in a `onload` event called from the `iframe`

thanks :)

Comment: Not Working bro.

Comment: try now please.