# How to mouse hover, highlight, and get properties of the DOM objects in a web page from external domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain, addeventlistener

I am trying to develop a web application which has functionality similar to the Element Selector in developer tools in Chrome. 
I need to open any URL from other different domains, inside a container in my app, and the page should appear exactly as it appears in normal browser, with all it styles. Then I should be able to hover over the elements in the opened page, highlight it, and display some property information about this element.

I created a simple Angular app and used `Iframe` tag to open the third party page.  But, when I try to attach event handlers, with `addEventListener`, to the DOM elements in the Iframe, I get the cross-domain error message.

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:4200" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I read some posts in stackoverflow like “Cross site contents cannot be read by JavaScript” and “If you don't have control over the framed site, you cannot circumvent the cross-domain policy.” For more details check the links:

[Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe)

[Cross domain iframe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue/9393545#9393545)

Following is my code:

```html
<iframe id="pFrame" onload="frameLoad();" src="" />
```

```
function frameLoad() {
    let frame = document.getElementById("pFrame");
    let iframeWindow = frame.contentWindow;
    iframeWindow.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver, true);
    iframeWindow.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut, true);
    iframeWindow.addEventListener("click", onClick, true);
}
```

Do you have any advice or maybe suggest different technique to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking the [Mozilla Goggles](https://goggles.mozilla.org/) project ?

It has an integrated editor, and their inspector seems to be very powerful.
Plus it don't require any application on your computer.