# is there a way to get the content height of embedded power-bi iframe and hide the scroll bar?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I tried following things to Remove Scroll bar ( because I need to get full content height)? There is an option called pageView='fitToWidth' to set full width (https://github.com/Pawani-DeSilva/powerbi-report-component/commit/238e91cfa0730fd9c3f5f7588a363aa6b31956bc) . It works as expected. My issue is related to height.

This is my learning

1. I cannot directly use https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) creates iFrame using javascript. 
   https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/blob/master/src/dashboard.ts#L51
2. browsers don't allow us to access DOM content of cross-domain iframe. Without accessing the DOM, I cannot get the content height. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170976
3. PowerBI does not have a proper solution to set content height. They have only fit to width.
   https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/iframe-scaling-issue/td-p/219827
   https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Turn-off-Horizontal-and-Vertical-scroll-bars-with-Filter-Pane/m-p/832461 (edited)

Answer (score 2):

If you set View => "Fit to Page" in Power BI Desktop or in Power BI portal then scroll bar will not appear.