# Selenium JavascriptExecutor doesnt return anything

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, google-chrome

I initialized a JavascriptExecutor but it doesn't return me what I want. Object is always null.

```
SeleniumDriver driver = new SeleniumDriver(DriverType.ChromeDriver);
    driver.get("https://www.xxxxxx.info/");
    driver.waitForPageToBeLoaded();
        
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver.getWebDriver();
    Object ob = js.executeScript("___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]");
```

Here what it gives me in console:

[image]

Why am I not able to get it via JavascriptExecutor?

Comment: Have you double checked ```___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]``` to make sure it returns not null?

Comment: @elMeroMero yes man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your js script should return it.try the below changes

`Object ob = js.executeScript("return ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]");`

so that your code will be like

```
SeleniumDriver driver = new SeleniumDriver(DriverType.ChromeDriver);
driver.get("https://www.xxxxxx.info/");
driver.waitForPageToBeLoaded();
    
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver.getWebDriver();
Object ob = js.executeScript("return ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]");
```

Since it is the JS object json it throws circular reference exception

You can convert to json using below js code

```
const getCircularReplacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};
JSON.stringify(___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0], getCircularReplacer());
```

Since it is cross origin iframe you can use it as chrome blocks it as shown in image below

[image]

Comment: gives me **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: circular reference**

Comment: Could you please provide me the URL?

Comment: https://www.vermittlerregister.info/recherche?a=suche&registernummer=D-W-156-WAPJ-13

Comment: @AhmetAzizBeşli It is HTML Dom circular reference and its not a valid json.You should get the required value from javascript and then you should return it to java

Comment: is it possible to convert that circular reference to JSON object ?

Comment: @AhmetAzizBeşli Refer to updated answer  You cannot make it as chrome blocks cross origin frame.See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170976/10858089