# How to capture events in an window that is loaded within a page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, selenium

Let's say I have a website called `https:// www.mysite.com`. I am trying to figure out how I can capture events (like button click) on some other site (say - `https://www.othersite.com` that is willingly loaded) inside of `mysite` (something like a `iframe`).

Note: I do not have access to `https://www.othersite.com`

Something like :

```
<my-site>

// load external site https://www.othersite.com here

</my-site>
```

I tried using iframes but I realised it's not possible due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). (Please do not suggest the `php` solution with `file_get_contents`. I have gone through all the articles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe) on stackoverflow in the last couple of days but could not find a JS solution to this).

Basically, I was looking at something similar to [Selenium IDE](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/) (It's extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd?hl=en)) where I want to capture events carried out by the user on `https://www.othersite.com` but its loaded on/inside `mysite`.

Any pointers to what can be some of the right approaches/strategies for solving this?
This is very fundamental question in what I am trying to achieve and I want to do it the right way. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pretty sure you don't have any options other than the one you don't want to do (scraping their content with something like PHP). And really, you shouldn't be able to do it without the consent of the other site for security reasons.

Comment: That's called cross site scripting and browser vendors work hard to make sure you can't do it.

Comment: @Drenai I mean I am exploring options. How do you think the selenium IDE does it? It is not a iframe I believe. By saying "something like an iframe" I wanted to establish that I am not rigid on it being an iframe but something similar in its features.

Comment: @Kinglish I see that the Selenium IDE does all the things that I want but not sure how they do it.