# Change current Date for IFrame

Tags: javascript, date, variables, iframe, set

In my school we are using a software called WebUntis to see if we have any substitute lessons. I display it through a iFrame on my Site. I noticed, if I change the Date of my Devices it would show me the plan for the day I have change my device to.
It is not getting passed to the iFrame, the site behind the iFrame stores the current date in a variable called dojoConfig:

```
var dojoConfig = {
...
grupet: {
...
"currentDate":"2023-08-06"
...
}
...
}
```

Is there any way to let the iFrame think it is another day, without manually changing my device setting?

I tried:

```
const z = new Date();
      z.setFullYear(2023, 8, 9);
```

Comment: if the iframe is on different website (domain) you can't access it programmatically [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170976/3807365)

Comment: Perhaps you're aware, but `z.setFullYear(2023, 8, 9)` sets the date to 9 Sep 2023. ;-)