# How to Change Background Image of a Div Element with Pointer-Events: None When It's Clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, pointer-events

I'm creating a mobile landing page by using a combination of two third-party pages embedded in iframes. One of the iframes has been optimized to display a volume button in 50x50 dimensions. The problem is that the sound is off by default and the volume control button is hidden. The iframe shows only a white background, which also doesn't suit the very dark background of the other iframe that takes most of the viewport. The speaker icon appears for a few seconds only when the 50x50 iframed area is touched / clicked, so a visitor has no clue they should touch it for turning the sound on.

I asked ChatGPT and it told me I could use JavaScript to do what I need, but it turned out to be a false information. JavaScript cannot capture a click event on an element that has click events disabled.

So far, the best solution that I could come up with is using pointer-events: none property on a static speaker icon that indicates the volume is turned off and placing it over the iframe with the hidden sound button. But it looks really weird when the sound is already on but the icon still shows it's off.

```html
<iframe
  frameborder="0"
  height="50"
  scrolling="no"
  src="speaker.html"
  style="bottom: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 1"
  width="50"
></iframe>

<div class="speaker"
  style="
    background-image: url('Sound-Off.png');
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50;
    z-index: 2"
></div>
```

The above alone works as I described but looks confusing to users since the icon doesn't switch to the "volume on" status.

```js
let isOn = false;
const element = document.querySelector('.speaker');
element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  isOn = !isOn;
  if (isOn) {
    element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("Sound-On.png")';
  } else {
    element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("Sound-Off.png")';
  }
});
```

This JavaScript snippet I made with the help of ChatGPT but turned out it doesn't work with `pointer-events: none`.

Please don't be misled by the same-origin URL in the iframe you see in the snippet. I'm using a hack of an iframe in an iframe in an iframe and the last iframe contains a cross-origin URL as I mentioned at the beginning as the "third-party" page.

Is there a simple workaround to make the sound icon change its status when clicked and letting the click to go through to the iframe beneath at the same time?

Comment: "I asked ChatGPT and it told me I could use JavaScript to do what I need, but it turned out to be a false information." — [Why do people keep using ChatGPT as a research tool?!](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2023/nov/02/australian-academics-apologise-for-false-ai-generated-allegations-against-big-four-consultancy-firms?CMP=Share_iOSApp_Other)

Comment: ChatGPT is an utter fool. It spits out words that sort of make sense, but it has no understanding of what it says.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe)

Comment: @imhvost I really don't know what to make of it. I'm not an expert in programming or web development. I either need a step-by-step instruction to solve my problem, or I'm afraid I cannot just come up with a solution myself by poiting me to another solved issue that obviously might have something to do with mine. But as I said I'm not any expert. I know nothing about JavaScript, just a few basics in HTML and CSS, but that's all.

Comment: hire a professional if ChatGPT can't help you and you can't do it yourself.

Comment: why are you using pointer none ?

Comment: @Afzal K. Because the content in the iframe is cross-origin and I don't know any of these super complex hacks how to send a click there without user interaction. Of course it would be great if there was a way how to send a click into that iframe automatically so the sound would be turned on aumatically without user interaction.

Comment: can you provide link to it?

Comment: you could use movemove event though, instead of click, it it helps

Comment: i just posted the answer, but have no idea how you are going to handle rest ? how change of image will turn on the sound etc etc

Comment: @Afzal I don't think it's a good idea to put the link here because it's an adult webcam room (not always online too). Regarding using the onmousemove event I'm not sure if it would work because the page I'm building with iframes gonna target mobile traffic only and there is no mouse moving, only touches. But as I mentioned earlier, I know only basics in building a web page so if it could work please provide more details how it possibly could work with onmousemove event. Maybe using onmousedown even would work to trigger an even with JavaScript when the div with pointer-events: none is touched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was pretty simple, I only needed to be a bit creative with the limitations I faced.

So, instead of using image of a red speaker with sound off for the static overlay with pointer-events: none, I created a new 50x50px image that says "AUDIO SWITCH" in the upper half and includes both speaker icons in the lower half, one red with sound off and the other green with sound on.

[This is how the new overlay image looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sV8h.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here i just wrapped div inside another div, so when this parent div is clicked, it will change the image of the inner div with pointer event none

```js
let isOn = false;
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
const element = document.querySelector('.speaker');
parent.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  isOn = !isOn;
  if (isOn) {
    //element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("Sound-On.png")';
    element.style.background = "green";
  } else {
    //element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("Sound-Off.png")';
    element.style.background = "red";
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.speaker {
    background: red;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<iframe
  frameborder="0"
  height="50"
  scrolling="no"
  src="speaker.html"
  style="bottom: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 1"
  width="50"
></iframe>

<div class="parent">
<div class="speaker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: still not sure if this is what you are looking for, but will change the image when clicked

Comment: I had this idea too of course, but the problem is that the parent div will not let the click to go through to the iframe underneath it with the lower z-index. Imagine that the child div with disabled pointer events is like a net that will let a drop of water to go through, but the parent div is a glass right under that child div and will block the drop anyway if the parent div has pointer events allowed. Maybe making the parent div's z-index lower than the iframe's would work? But I think that would automatically make the child div's z-index also lower than the iframe's since it would inherit.

Comment: well if you can add youtube iframe and let me know what you are looking to do with click, perhaps it could be sorted

Comment: As I described above, I have used an iframe in an iframe in an iframe hack to get the sound button exactly where I need it and scaled up by 200%. So now I have the sound button from a cross-origin page in the parent iframe 50x50px. But the button shows up only when touched (interacted with). That's why I need to place a custom overlay speaker icon over the iframe which will let the click to go through to the iframe underneath and change its status from off to on. If this is not possible, which I suppose isn't, then I have to keep the icon status to be always off even when sound was turned on.