Can't access a certain element due to it being in a Iframe
I'm currently trying to develop a chrome extension where it relys on an video element. When I try to access it I get hit with an error.
The first code I wrote was where it would just log if the iframe element is found then if the video is found Below:
console.log("Content script loaded");

let iframe = document.getElementsByClassName('video-player')[0];
console.log("Iframe:", iframe);

// Check if iframe exists
if (iframe) {
    // Access the content window of the iframe
    let iframeContentWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
    console.log("Iframe content window:", iframeContentWindow);

    let iframeDocument = iframeContentWindow.document;
    console.log("Iframe document:", iframeDocument);

    let videoElement = iframeDocument.getElementById('player0');
    console.log("Video element:", videoElement);

    // Check if video element exists
    if (videoElement) {
        // Perform actions on the video element
        console.log("Current time:", videoElement.currentTime); // Read currentTime property
    } else {
        console.log("Video element not found within the iframe.");
    }
} else {
    console.log("Iframe not found on the page.");
}

Well that didn't work because the iframe wasn't found due to the page loading it dynamically. So I then adjusted the script and added SetTimeout.
function checkForIframe() {
    let iframe = document.getElementsByClassName('video-player')[0];
    console.log("Iframe:", iframe);

    if (iframe) {
        let iframeContentWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
        console.log("Iframe content window:", iframeContentWindow);

        let iframeDocument = iframeContentWindow.document;
        console.log("Iframe document:", iframeDocument);

        let videoElement = iframeDocument.getElementById('player0');
        console.log("Video element:", videoElement);

        if (videoElement) {
            console.log("Current time:", videoElement.currentTime); 
        } else {
            console.log("Video element not found within the iframe.");
            // If video element not found, check again after a delay
            setTimeout(checkForIframe, 1000);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Iframe not found on the page.");
        // If iframe not found, check again after a delay
        setTimeout(checkForIframe, 1000);
    }
}


checkForIframe();


This allowed the script to find the iframe but now I run into another problem.When trying to get the video inside the iframe it gave me a error.The error says "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read a named property 'document' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.crunchyroll.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://static.crunchyroll.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."
I found a postthat lead me to another post that says to enable "all_frames" in my manifest file so I did yet I still run into the same problem.
Manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "JWatch",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Sync Crunchyroll Video with friends to watch together",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.crunchyroll.com/*"],
      "js": ["src/scripts/content.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://www.crunchyroll.com/*",
    "*://static.crunchyroll.com/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "src/scripts/background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "src/html/popup.html"
  }
}


The site is Crunchyroll and I'm trying to make a virtual room where multiple users can join and watch content together. The video element I'm trying to access has an ID called 'player0'.

Welcome to the community!
This is a cross-site scripting (XSS) issue not your plugin. You either have to host the script on the same subdomain as your iframe or use a recommended way of sharing data across domains using postMessage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage
Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170976/9101039

what ........>?
